# Como incluir um js de outro domínio no html?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá,
tenho um arquivo .js em http://meudominio.com/arquivo.js. Gostaria de chamá-lo em outro local (meudominio2.com) com `<script src="meudominio.com/arquivo.js" ></script>`, porém, dá file not found. E o nome está correto e posso acessá-lo através do navegador.
Então a questão é essa: como incluir esse .js para que eu possa trabalhar com ele em outra página?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especifique o protocolo

Um modo genérico onde torna-se compatível com https e http:

```
<script src="//meudominio.com/arquivo.js" ></script>
```

Caso queira um protocolo específico

```
<script src="http://meudominio.com/arquivo.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para importar qualquer arquivo na web, primeiro o arquivo tem que estar na internet.

Notei também que você escreveu `<script src="meudominio.com/arquivo.js" ></script>`, esquecendo o **http://**, tente inserir assim: `<script src="http://meudominio.com/arquivo.js" ></script>`